# Is it possible to use camel-2.16.2 with servicemix 5.6.0 and karaf -2.4.4?

Tags: apache-camel, compatibility, apache-servicemix, jetty-9

In our application we have encountered impotency issue which is fixed by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9480. we are currently using service mix 5.5.0 with following dependencies.

Activiti 5.17.0
Apache ActiveMQ 5.11.1
Apache Camel 2.15.2
Apache CXF 3.0.4
Apache Karaf 2.4.3 .

So in-order to get fix for CAMEL-9480, i tried to upgrade camel to 2.16.2 by doing service mix upgrade to 5.6.0 which supports following dependencies

Activiti 5.19.0.2
Apache ActiveMQ 5.12.3
Apache Camel 2.16.2
Apache CXF 3.1.4
Apache Karaf 2.4.4

after upgrade i am getting following error during deployment

```
 [caused by: Unable to resolve 295.0: missing requirement [295.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)(version>=9.2.0)(!(version>=10.0.0)))]
```

when i checked camel-jetty-2.16.2.pom,it uses camel-jetty9 and in karaf features its mentioned as below.

```
<details>camel-jetty9 intend to work with jetty9, so this feature only works in the karaf container which support jetty9, e.g. karaf 4.x</details>
```

so is it possible to use camel-2.16.2 with karaf 2.4.4 or we need upgrade to karaf 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

There are two bundles and two features:

- `camel-jetty` which support jetty8 (and Karaf 2/3)
- `camel-jetty9` which support jetty9 and Karaf 4

However, It depends too on the other camel features you use. Some feature uses a feature jetty without versions, other use directly camel-jetty9 or camel-jetty, etc. Sometimes, It necessary to rewrite some feature to fix a version range, but in most case, it works out of the box.

Comment: yes there are two bundles but camel-jetty has dependency on camel-jetty9 in camel-2.16.2 would that effect ?

Comment: if you are talking about the bundle "camel-jetty", it's not used in the features. you should read the features.xml, you'll see what is installed and the needed dependencies